# R Time Series, date isn't being read properly

Tags: r, date, time, series

I have this data that I want to plot as a time series.

```
    Date    Units.Sold
1   Jan-16  588
2   Feb-16  448
3   Mar-16  490
4   Apr-16  512
5   May-16  528
6   Jun-16  432
7   Jul-16  470
8   Aug-16  446
9   Sep-16  465
10  Oct-16  388
11  Nov-16  429
12  Dec-16  414
```

However, when I use ts(datasetName), I get this:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 12 
Frequency = 1 
   Date Units.Sold
 1    5        588
 2    4        448
 3    8        490
 4    1        512
 5    9        528
 6    7        432
 7    6        470
 8    2        446
 9   12        465
10   11        388
11   10        429
12    3        414
```

As you can see, the dates are in the wrong order. I want January to correspond with 1, February with 2, and so on. Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you have code you can show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your column named `'Date'` to a `Date` - class object first. You can use `as.Date` for that, but you'll need to add a year first.

```
your_year <- 2018
df$Date <- as.Date(paste0(df$Date, '-', your_year), format = '%b-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: When I do that, it gives me this error:
Error in df$Date : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Is your data in an object called `df`, and is the name of the Date column `"Date"`?

Comment: I'm not sure if my data is in an object called df, I'm very new to R. I had a .csv file, and I used the "Import dataset" button. I believe my Date column is called Date? I didn't ever name it

Comment: you'll need to replace `df` with whatever your data frame is named, and `Date` with whatever your Date column is named. I don't think I can help you figure out what your data frame is named, I'm unfamiliar with the Graphical tool you mention. If you import a csv in code, with e.g. the function `read.csv`, you have to name it yourself, so I would suggest doing that.